# How to get a length of lists in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
                                                             List
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]
2009-12-14 14:29:32             [happy new year, happy birthday,]
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]
```

how do I get something like this

```
                                                             List Len
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]   3
2009-12-14 14:29:32             [happy new year, happy birthday,]   2
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]   4
```

I tried df['List'].str.len(),
but it returns the length in terms of how many words are in this list.

Comment: What is `print (type(df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('List')]))` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is nice, if lists in column `List`:

```
print (type(df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('List')]))
<class 'list'>

df['Len'] = df['List'].str.len()
```

Solution if not missing values:

```
df['Len'] = df['List'].apply(len)
```

---

If not, first remove possible `,` in start of end by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then count number of `,` with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
print (type(df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('List')]))
<class 'str'>

df['Len'] = df['List'].str.strip(' ,[]').str.count(',') + 1
print (df)
                                                             List  Len
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]    3
2009-12-14 14:29:32             [happy new year, happy birthday,]    2
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]    4
```

If need also convert values to lists:

```
df['List'] = df['List'].str.strip(' ,[]').str.split(', ')
print (type(df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('List')]))
<class 'list'>

df['Len'] = df['List'].str.len()
print (df)
                                                             List  Len
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]    3
2009-12-14 14:29:32              [happy new year, happy birthday]    2
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
df['Len']=df['List'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

**Ex.**

```
df['Len'] = df['List'].transform(len)
print(df)

                                                             List  Len
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]    3
2009-12-14 14:29:32              [happy new year, happy birthday]    2
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]    4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your List column is str:

```
df['Len'] = df['List'].map(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not find any problem with your code. It should work fine. As mentioned by @moys you can also use apply method to create a new column which contains the length of the list column.

```
df['length']=df['List'].apply(lambda row: len(row))
print(df)
                                                             List  length
2013-12-22 15:25:02  [good morning, good afternoon, good evening]    3
2009-12-14 14:29:32              [happy new year, happy birthday]    2
2013-12-22 15:42:00                      [happy, sad, mad, chill]    4
```

Let me know if you have any issues regarding this.